# It doesn't go through the data

Tags: python

It gives

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

as an error.

```
year= int(input("enter year"))
chk_year=year[2:4]
```

I did try this one first but it didn't work.
Then I tried using:

```
chk_year=str(year[2:4]) and 
chk_year=int(str(year[2:4]))
```

but it still doesn't work. How can i fix it?

Comment: In your first line, you're converting the result from the input statement into an `int`. Then, in your second statement, you're trying to slice it as if it were a string. Try `year=input("enter year")` at which point, your `chk_year=year[2:4]` statement should work - or at least, shouldn't error.

Comment: the way you are accessing can only be done in string so change that to `chk_year=str(year)[2:4]`

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert it to string first to check the subscript part
i.e. first convert to string then do [2:4]

```
year= int(input("enter year"))
chk_year=str(year)[2:4]
```

or since you are only concerned about the last 2 digits of the year do `% 100`

```
year= int(input("enter year"))
chk_year=year % 100
if chk_year == 19:
    print("it is current")
```